# Swith trailing stop in MQL4

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, expert-advisor

I am working on this little RSI Expert Advisor in MQL4. It is trading fine at taking buys and sels but I just can´t get my trailing stop to work. I am going mad..:-)

I have added the code below. It is an simple EA based on the RSI. I would just like to add an trailing stop whenever a buy or sell trade is taken.

Can anyone see the problem?

```
// Define parameters for your EA outside of functions
input int takeProfit = 20;   // Take Profit value in pips
input int stopLoss = 50;     // Stop Loss value in pips
input int trailingStop = 50; // Trailing stop distance in pips

// Flag to track if a trade has been placed in the current tick
bool tradePlaced = false;

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert tick function                                             |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTick()
{
    // Reset the tradePlaced flag at the beginning of each tick
    tradePlaced = false;

    // We create a string variable for the signal
    string signal = "";

    // Calculate the RSI value
    double RSIValue = iRSI(_Symbol, _Period, 14, PRICE_CLOSE, 0);

    // Declare take profit and stop loss variables
    double takeProfitLevel, stopLossLevel;

    // If it is above 70
    if (RSIValue > 70)
    {
        signal = "sell";
        takeProfitLevel = Bid - takeProfit * _Point;
        stopLossLevel = Bid + stopLoss * _Point;
    }

    // If it is below 30
    if (RSIValue < 30)
    {
        signal = "buy";
        takeProfitLevel = Ask + takeProfit * _Point;
        stopLossLevel = Ask - stopLoss * _Point;
    }

    // Buy or sell 10 Microlot based on the signal
    if (OrdersTotal() == 0 && !tradePlaced)
    {
        if (signal == "buy")
        {
            int buyTicket = OrderSend(_Symbol, OP_BUY, 0.50, Ask, 3, 0, takeProfitLevel, "Buy Order", 0, stopLossLevel, Green);
            if (buyTicket > 0)
            {
                Print("Buy Order placed successfully. Ticket: ", buyTicket);
                tradePlaced = true; // Set the flag to true
            }
            else
            {
                Print("Error placing Buy Order. Error code: ", GetLastError());
            }
        }
        else if (signal == "sell")
        {
            int sellTicket = OrderSend(_Symbol, OP_SELL, 0.50, Bid, 3, 0, takeProfitLevel, "Sell Order", 0, stopLossLevel, Red);
            if (sellTicket > 0)
            {
                Print("Sell Order placed successfully. Ticket: ", sellTicket);
                tradePlaced = true; // Set the flag to true
            }
            else
            {
                Print("Error placing Sell Order. Error code: ", GetLastError());
            }
        }
    }

    // Trailing stop logic
if (OrdersTotal() > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < OrdersTotal(); i++)
    {
        if (OrderSelect(i, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_TRADES))
        {
            // Check if the order is a Buy or Sell order
            if (OrderSymbol() == _Symbol)
            {
                double currentProfit = OrderProfit();
                double openPrice = OrderOpenPrice();
                double trailingStopLevel;

                // Calculate the trailing stop level
                if (OrderType() == OP_BUY)
                {
                    trailingStopLevel = openPrice + trailingStop * _Point;
                }
                else if (OrderType() == OP_SELL)
                {
                    trailingStopLevel = openPrice - trailingStop * _Point;
                }

                // Update the stop loss to the trailing stop level
                double newStopLoss = 0;
                if (OrderType() == OP_BUY)
                {
                    newStopLoss = MathMax(openPrice + currentProfit - trailingStop * _Point, trailingStopLevel);
                }
                else if (OrderType() == OP_SELL)
                {
                    newStopLoss = MathMin(openPrice + currentProfit + trailingStop * _Point, trailingStopLevel);
                }

                if (newStopLoss != OrderStopLoss())
                {
                    if (OrderModify(OrderTicket(), OrderOpenPrice(), newStopLoss, OrderTakeProfit(), 0, Green))
                    {
                        Print("Trailing Stop updated successfully. Ticket: ", OrderTicket());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Print("Error updating Trailing Stop. Error code: ", GetLastError());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


    // Chart output for the signal
    Comment("The current signal is: ", signal);
}
```

I am hoping someone can see the issue and guide me in the right direction

Can anyone see the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to

> normalizeDouble(newStopLoss,_Digits)

when setting it.